# Android Calender.getTimeInMillis() units?

Tags: java, android

I am using Android's Calendar object and I am using the getTimeInMillis() method, but when I look at the Value it gives me it is a really long number. I am trying to replicate this format but I don't know how as when I take the current time in 24 hour mode and convert it to milliseconds I am completely off.

Example:

Calendar.getTimeInMillis() : at 11:46 pm = 1,349,585,220,205

Time at 11:46 pm using formula[(23 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (46 * 60 * 1000)] = 85,560,000

I'm wondering if there is some kind of formula the calendar is using to convert the current time to Milliseconds and how I can replicate this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need current time in milliseconds?

Comment: I'm trying to create in app to add an event to the calendar using the programming and the app wouldn't let me add events since they were so far into the past. The Android Calendar uses milliseconds to add event times in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of milliseconds since the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), 1/1/1970. See this article on [Unix time.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

```
1,349,585,220,205 milliseconds / (1000 * 3600) = number of hours = 374884.7833902778
374884.7833902778 hours / 24 = 15620.19930792824 days
15620.19930792824 days / 365 days = 42.79506659706368 years

1970 + 42 years = 2012
```

(This is not precise due to not taking into account daylight savings time. Use a real datetime library!)

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense now. I never would have guessed that.